# Insert the same Non-Blank Rows every nth row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to be able to insert the same 5 rows of data between every row on an Excel sheet. The 5 rows are not blank but contain specific data that needs to be repeated. The source of the 5 rows could be on a second sheet or rows 2 through 6 on `sheet 1`, which ever works best. Copy and pasting manually unfortunately is not an option as there are hundreds of lines. Is anyone able to provide some guidance as to how to accomplish this task?

Comment: in the title you say **every nth row** but in the question text you say **every row**, which is the right one? and until which row? what is the last row number that you want it happen, otherwise it will go indefinite number of rows.

Comment: did my answer help to solve your question?

Comment: Sorry for the delay... To clarify, I need to be able to insert 5 rows of data between the existing rows of data on sheet 1.  Sheet one contains 200 rows of data.  I must insert 5 rows between each of those 200 lines.

Comment: hi john, how many columns are there in sheet 2

Comment: @JohnBongiovanni i edited my answer and now it copies the **A1:A5** from `Sheet2` and pastes it every one line in `column A` of the active sheet on which you are running the macro in. tell me if you have problems

Comment: Thanks guys.  I'll give it a shot later today and I'll let you know how it goes.  By the way, each sheet has 17 columns

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a macro to do this:

```
Sub PasteRangeEveryNthRow()
Dim RW As Long, i As Long
RW = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A5").Copy
For i = 1 To RW Step 1
    Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
Next i
End Sub
```

This code presupposes that you are copying the range **A1:A5** from `SHEET2` and pasting it every **one line** until the last data in the column **A**.

basically, you need to press **<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>** to open the VBA window in excel , then go to **INSERT**>**MODULE** and paste this code there. 
 Then run this macro from the **developer** tab in excel.

if you don't see the developer tab in your excel, go to the options and enable it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula in your `sheet 2` like below:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(FLOOR(ROW()-1;5)/5+1;1))
```

By using this formula you will have each rows 5 times dynamically, that as soon as any change on `sheet1`; data in `sheet 2` will be updated.

If you want to make them static `Copy` your data and `Paste` them with `Values Only` option.